How to apply Pandas TA to a DataFame to calculate EMA of different lengths using Pandas Groupby
I have a dataframe that contains data of multiple symbols and is grouped by symbols:

I am trying to calculate the EMA 20 for high, low and close values using the code below:
def calculate_ema(self, df):
        df= self.data.copy()
        ema_calculation = ta.Strategy(name = "EMA Calculator", 
                                      description= "EMA",
                                      ta = [{"kind":"ema", "close":"low", "length": 20, "suffix": 'Low'},
                                            {"kind":"ema", "close":"high", "length": 20, "suffix": 'High'},
                                            {"kind":"ema", "close":"close", "length": 20, "suffix": 'Close'},   
                                        ]
                                    )
        df.ta.strategy(ema_calculation)
        self.data = df
        return self.data

    def calculate_indicator(self): #, backcandles
        df= self.data.copy()
        df1 = df.groupby(by =["symbol"], as_index=False).apply(self.calculate_ema)
        self.data =df1
        return self.data`

However the above code returns a dataframe with 5.9 million rows wher as the original dataframe has only 38 348 rows.
I tried a workaround solution as below but that is also returning a dataframe with 5.9 million rows.
 def calculate_ema_low(self, df):
        df= self.data.copy()
        df['EMA_Low_20'] = ta.ema(df.groupby(by =["symbol"])["low"].transform(lambda x: ta.ema(x, length=20, append=True)))
        self.data=df
        return self.data
    
    def calculate_ema_high(self, df):
        df= self.data.copy()
        self.data['EMA_High_20'] = ta.ema(self.data.groupby(by =["symbol"])["high"].transform(lambda x: ta.ema(x, length=20, append=True)))
        self.data=df
        return self.data
    
    def calculate_ema_close(self, df):
        df= self.data.copy()
        self.data['EMA_Close_20'] = ta.ema(self.data.groupby(by =["symbol"])["close"].transform(lambda x: ta.ema(x, length=20, append=True)))
        self.data=df
        return self.data
    
    def calculate_indicator( self): 
        df= self.data.copy() 
        df1 = df.groupby(by =["symbol"], as_index=False).apply(self.calculate_ema_low)
        df2 = df.groupby(by =["symbol"], as_index=False).apply(self.calculate_ema_high)
        df3 = df.groupby(by =["symbol"], as_index=False).apply(self.calculate_ema_close)
        
        df1["EMA_High_20"]=df2["EMA_High_20"]
        df1["EMA_Close_20"]=df3["EMA_Close_20"]

        self.data =df1
        return self.data


Please don't use local words like lac here. A lot of people will have no idea what are lac rows.

A faster solution maybe is to loop over each symbol data["symbol"].unique() and then do the ta.Summarize(...) for each filtered row and then finally pd.concat([ta_func(data[data["symbol"] == symbol) for symbol in data["symbol"].unique()], ignore_index = True)
